# Using getElementById on iframe from iframe in opened window

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

I'm trying to alter the value of a certain textfield that's located in the iframe (a) that is the opener of a new window (b), which in his place contains an iframe (c) from which i want to alter that value.

Schematically it looks like (a) --> (b (c))

So basically I should have something like

```
<a onClick="parent.opener.getElementById('Message').value+='NewValue'">LinkName</a>
```

Except this doesn't work and gives me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getElementById'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parent.opener.document.getElementById()